# Restrict an IP address to the internet only

Tags: networking, router

Can I restrict, a static IP address on my network, to internet access but no other internal IPs should be accessible (apart from the gateway)?
Is there a routing option for such a thing on home routers?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many routers with so many different facilities that one cannot generalise. On some a single port can be assigned as a DMZ (demilitarised zone), so this would provide the isolation you need if assigned to the machine in question; on others there is no DMZ, or the DMZ works differently. Note that a machine in a DMZ needs very good internet security protection.

You could achieve the result you want by setting all the firewalls on the subnet to reject the port assigned to the machine in question, but this would not stop access to webcams and the like, which do not have firewalls.

You would need administrator rights on the machine that you want to exclude, and its users would need to be excluded from the same, so that they cannot assign their own, different static address within the same subnet, thereby bypassing the firewall blocks or taking it out of the DMZ.